# jQuery get class and use to change attribute

Tags: jquery, css, class

If I want to get the body class of a page and then use the class in a function. How do I add the (dot) as in .class?

My code is

`var wotClass = $('body').attr('class');`

This gives me the body class as (e01 c01 p01). If I want to use this in a function or to make a change as follows:

`if($('.nav__items').css('display') == 'block') {
    $(wotClass + ' .chapter_link').attr('aria-expanded' , 'true');`
}
trouble is this calls (e01 c03 p01 .chapter_link) instead of (.e01 .c03 .p01 .chapter_link).

Is it possible to make this work. Thanks in advance.

What I am trying to achieve is. Depending on the body class a section of a menu is expanded. The default attribute is:
`$('.chapter_link').attr('aria-expanded' , 'false');`

So if the body class is (e1 c03 p01) the attribute changes to true.

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add every dot to each class and concat them with no space between. You can achieve that by using split and join(".").

```js
var wotClass = "." + $('body').attr('class').split(/\s+/).join(".");
document.write(wotClass);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="a1 a2 a3 a4"></body>
```

Comment: Brilliant that works. Many thanks to all for the help.

Comment: i think you should include explanation for this `.split(/\s+/)`

Answer (score 0):

You should have to explode all the returned string and concat it with `.` :

```
var 
    wotClass = $('body').attr('class'),
    exp      = wotClass.split(' '),
    newClass = $.map(exp, function (e, i) {
         return '.' + e;
    }).join( ' ' );

$(newClass+ ' .chapter_link').attr('aria-expanded' , 'true');
```

Comment: Thanks Norlihazmey Ghazali. Both methods work but give slightly different results. Both are useful to know.